# Year in which it was established and subjects of study of height/weight index

Tags: bodyweight

I read in the wikipedia some time ago that the height/weight index was generated using statistics taken from soldiers as subjects of study in the war, but now I can't find the article.

For the records... I'm particularly interested in whether it is being updated, and how so often, and if it was repeated using updated data.

Comment: I don't see a connection between what you're asking and the scope of this site. Questions are expected to be related to fitness or exercise routines. Please see our [faq] for more information.

Comment: @MattChan Couldn't find some other SE site to ask, this is the closest to a health SE site, the second closest is the coocking site, AFAIK